# Do I need to use the esc_html() function on hard coded links?

Tags: security, links, site-url, escaping

I understand when using certain WP functions like site_url(); you should escape these with the esc_html(); function in the following manner:

```
<?php esc_html(site_url()) ?>
```

My question is, if I have inputted the site url manually in a template file such as front-page.php like this:

```
<a href="//mysite.com">My Site</a>
```

Do I still need to use the esc_html() function? It doesn't mention anything about this use-case in the docs. And if so how do I go about this?

Many thanks

Comment: `esc_html()` wouldn't be the correct function for links. You'd use `esc_url()`, but you don't need to for hard-coded links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, you don't need to escape hard-coded URLs.

Comment: A note on why you don't need to escape hardcoded static strings would be great :)

Comment: But you would need to escape links which are not hardcoded, but populated from backend via an admin?